# Move Folders in Google Drive Using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I was wondering if someone could take a look at this for me.

- The goal

My company has a ton of client folders on google drive that are full of content (files and folders). I'm trying to take all of the existing content, and move it into a newly created folder within each client folder named "old client work".

- The issue

When I run the code, there's an issue with moving folders. Creating the "old client work" folder works fine, as does moving existing files into it. But the code runs into an error when trying to move folders.

- The code

Here is the code I have:

```
function createOldClientWorkFolder() {
    var clientContentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("IDhere");
    var clientFolders = clientContentFolder.getFolders();
    while(clientFolders.hasNext()) {
        var client = clientFolders.next();
        var oldWorkFolder = client.createFolder('Old Client Work');
        var clientContentFiles = client.getFiles();
        var clientContentFolders = client.getFolders();
        while (clientContentFiles.hasNext()) {
              var fileToMove = clientContentFiles.next();
              fileToMove.moveTo(oldWorkFolder)
        }

        while (clientContentFolders.hasNext()) {
              var folderToMove = clientContentFolders.next();
              folderToMove.moveTo(oldWorkFolder)
        }


    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [so]., Please add the textual error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

(Since you haven't provided a log/error message I'm guessing here, but I encountered something similar a while ago while trying to move folders so I thought this might help.)

`moveTo` requires that you have permission to the object that you're trying to move itself. Could there be a possibility that your app script doesn't have the write permission to the actual client folder? (`moveTo` modifies the `parent` property of the folder object you're trying to move, so you also read write permission, not just read).